# Prevent hackers from replacing our website's index file

Tags: php, security

This is 4th time for our concern, somebody is hacking all our websites and replacing our index file (the homepage) with a homepage they created, effectively defacing them.

This time, our websites have been hacked by the hacker group [XcoDerz Security](https://www.facebook.com/Th3CoderzBoat/timeline?ref=page_internal). Please help me protect against this type of website defacement hacking.

Basically, the attackers are replacing my sites' index files with different index file with some new content. What security technologies are available to help defend my websites' index files?

Comment: Have a better password / protection.

Comment: Get yourself over to Hack this site: https://www.hackthissite.org/ take the challenges and learn how to prevent it. - without seeing any code, logs etc we cant tell you how they did it.

Comment: we are using random password only. Even though they are hacking.

Comment: Situations like these call for an expert, hire one. You won't get any solution here.

Comment: How can anybody be expected to provide you with any useful help. You give zero information. For heavans sake get a grip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, change your FTP details. Then check your FTP files for any JS that could be interrogated, or file upload forms? Remove them.

You could try contacting your Web Hosting provider and inform them of what's happening, and supply them with IP addresses if you have them. They may be able to put things in place from their end to block these hackers.

Comment: What? This is NOT an un-useful answer!

Comment: When they hacked first time itself we have changed password for ftp and databases by random password generation. Even though we are facing this issue

Comment: It sounds like they're getting in somewhere else, do you have PHP script or JS scripts running?

Comment: Yes, we have php and js scripts

Comment: Okay, can you remove any thirdparty JS script, as that's most likely doing it. Or it could be that your web host has infected servers. Check with them, and report your hacking activity to them.

Comment: Okey sure, we will do as you say and will check it. Thanks

Comment: No problem, I hope I've helped, or answered your question somewhat!